# jquery append does not append large html comming from a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

It´s is not very clear to me why I am not get any data appended when I have a lot of data to be appended.

When I have 3 objects It works fine, for a larger number it does not append data.
I believe that append is been called before the for loop is finished. Could be that?

**building the `<tr>`'s:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].indiceId === 4 && dinamicDom !== 'dinamic_index_busca_edit') {
        var dateChkBox = '<p class="pDtPeriodoChk"><input type="checkbox" name="dtPeriodoChk" class="dtPeriodoChk" id="' + i + '_chk">Por Período</p>';
        trs = trs + '<tr class="' + dinamicDom + '" style="padding-top:10px;"><td class="smallMediumField ' + i + '" style="padding-top:10px;"><fieldset class="dataFieldset"><legend>' + obj[i].indiceName + '</legend>' + dateChkBox + '<span id="' + i + '_lblDtInicio" class="lblDataInicio" style="display:none"><br />Data Inicio:</span><table><tr><td><img src="/Images/equal.png" alt="Igual a"/></td><td><input type="text" id="' + i + '" name="data" class="selectInput limpar" ';

        if (obj[i].valor !== null && obj[i].valor !== '') {
            trs = trs + ' value="' + obj[i].valor + '" ';
        }    
        trs = trs + '></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" id="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" name="data_indices" value="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" class="selectInput"></fieldset></td></tr>';
   } else {
       trs = trs + '<tr class="' + dinamicDom + '"><td class="smallMediumField ' + i + '" style="padding-top:10px;">' + obj[i].indiceName + '<br /><input type="text" id="' + i + '" name="groupBusca" class="selectInput limpar" ';
       if (obj[i].valor !== null && obj[i].valor !== '') {
           trs = trs + ' value="' + obj[i].valor + '" ';
       }
       trs = trs + '></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" id="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" name="indicesBusca" value="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" class="selectInput"></td></tr>';
   }
```

}

**appending:**

```
$('#tblBusca').append(trs);
```

Comment: Could you add this line: `console.log(trs);` after the loop and show the output at your JS console?

Comment: Why not use DOM elements instead of HTML strings? It sure would result  in more maintainable code.

Comment: @FelixKling  What you mean 'use DOM elements'? Some sort of help function? Sorry for the newb question

Comment: Instead of creating a long HTML string, create DOM elements and use DOM manipulation to combine them. E.g. `$tr = $('<tr />'); $tr.append($('<td />'))`.

Comment: Nice... thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending row by row

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var trs;

    if (obj[i].indiceId === 4 && dinamicDom !== 'dinamic_index_busca_edit') {
        var dateChkBox = '<p class="pDtPeriodoChk"><input type="checkbox" name="dtPeriodoChk" class="dtPeriodoChk" id="' + i + '_chk">Por Período</p>';
        trs = trs + '<tr class="' + dinamicDom + '" style="padding-top:10px;"><td class="smallMediumField ' + i + '" style="padding-top:10px;"><fieldset class="dataFieldset"><legend>' + obj[i].indiceName + '</legend>' + dateChkBox + '<span id="' + i + '_lblDtInicio" class="lblDataInicio" style="display:none"><br />Data Inicio:</span><table><tr><td><img src="/Images/equal.png" alt="Igual a"/></td><td><input type="text" id="' + i + '" name="data" class="selectInput limpar" ';

        if (obj[i].valor !== null && obj[i].valor !== '') {
            trs = trs + ' value="' + obj[i].valor + '" ';
        }    
        trs = trs + '></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" id="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" name="data_indices" value="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" class="selectInput"></fieldset></td></tr>';
   } else {
       trs = trs + '<tr class="' + dinamicDom + '"><td class="smallMediumField ' + i + '" style="padding-top:10px;">' + obj[i].indiceName + '<br /><input type="text" id="' + i + '" name="groupBusca" class="selectInput limpar" ';
       if (obj[i].valor !== null && obj[i].valor !== '') {
           trs = trs + ' value="' + obj[i].valor + '" ';
       }
       trs = trs + '></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" id="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" name="indicesBusca" value="' + obj[i].indiciId + '" class="selectInput"></td></tr>';
   }

    $('#tblBusca').append(trs);
}
```